# Jenkins configuration to access in different AWS servers in same network

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, configuration

Jenkins is installed in a AWS server as war file in the windows OS environment , and i want to access the link in another AWS servers which are of same network , ports have been opened , still am not able to access the localhost link / system domain link in the other servers.

Help is appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to access it can you paste a code or command some thing?

Comment: Am try to access it in this way , "http://systemdomainname:8080/"  and system domain name is the name of the system where jenkins is installed.

Comment: Do you have port 8080 open in security group for both EC2 instances?

Comment: Yes actually we asked tech team to create a link which can be accessed by every one in the network , as per the requirement ports have been opened (I hope so) , still if I use jenkins URL in the other server or locally , am not able to access it with the url provided , my local host :8080 is working fine. .according to tech team they asked me to configure in jenkins itself.

Comment: Do I need to use port 80 instead ? for running jenkins ? tech team said "requested url www.example.com , is pointing to your server (where jenkins is installed) , configure jenkins accordingly . now please suggest , am I missing something in configuration ?

Comment: Did you check if Jenkins is serving port 8080.

Comment: yes.. jenkins / configure page showing 8080

Comment: Any update on this please ?